# lme4 error: fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 4 columns / coefficients boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

Tags: r, lme4

I did a nested experiment to see the changes in chorophyll production in quinoa plant. I have 4 factor:
light: Blue, Red, Far Red, White,
NaCl_Concentration: 0mM, 200mM
Variety: Bastille, Tunkahuan, Chimborazo, Canar
Time: 0h, 24h, 672h
Replicates: 1, 2, 3, 4

The code that I'm using:

```
model_lmer <- lmer(Chlorophyll ~ Light * NaCl_Concentration * Variety * Time + 
                     (1 | Replicates) +
                     (1 | Light:NaCl_Concentration) +
                     (1 | Light:NaCl_Concentration:Variety),
                   data = quinoa_data)
```

**fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 4 columns / coefficients
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')**

I'm very new to this package and I don't know how to solve it. I also try to use the package 'agricolae' whichs is user friendly but I couldn't introduce the time factor on i

I try to install this packages again:

```
install.packages("Matrix")
install.packages("Rtools")
```

**And I solve this problem:**

function 'cholmod_factor_ldetA' not provided by package 'Matrix'

**But I keep having the same error: **

fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 4 columns / coefficients
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

I think this problem arise because my experiment has unbalaced replicates or Im doing a complex analysis when I just need a simply analysis